# gerrit-trigger server cannot remove as server name has https://

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

when I create new server for gerrit trigger, I accidentally typed name as https://x.x.x.x:8080. After saving it, I cannot open edit page of this server or remove it on http://localhost:8080/jenkins/gerrit-trigger/ page. How can I remove this server in other ways?

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why you can't edit/remove it?

Comment: when I click the edit or remove button, it opens a blank page